# Vaadin Grid focus loss when using Interactive mode with refresh row

Tags: vaadin, keyboard-shortcuts, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

We have a Vaadin 14 Grid with some columns being rendered using a component renderer to display a number field. And then there are columns that use the input values to recalculate some data. The problem occurs when the user focuses a number field using a keyboard or mouse, and changes the value in any number field. At the backend, we are refreshing the row using `dataprovider.refreshItem` to display the updated data. But during this operation we lose focus on the input field, which disturbs the whole UX experience.

```
addColumn(new ComponentRenderer<>(item -> {
            AmountField amountField = new AmountField(
            amountField.setWidth("7em");
            amountField.addValueChangeListener(ignored -> changed(item, amountField.getIntegerValue()));
            
         return amountField;
        }));

private void palettChanged(Item item, Integer value) {
    // do some chnages in the other properties of item 

    getDataProvider().refreshItem(item); // i loose focus after calling this 


}
```

Comment: Which Vaadin version are you using?

Comment: <vaadin.version>14.4.1</vaadin.version>

Comment: Hi, can you provide some snippets of the code so we can have a better understanding of the issue?

Comment: added code snippet